# Combining MVC 5 routing with Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

After reading a couple of Web Api 2 articles I decided to give it a try and use it in my current project because there is a lot of JSON data being send between the Views and the backend services. I'm making it a multipage application.

What I can't figure out is how to keep the routing from MVC and combine this with Web Api 2 to handle the data communication. Here are a couple of options that crossed my mind:

1. Creating 2 seperate projects: a MVC projects that handles to routing using controllers and returning views and a webapi projects that handles the data. (How will they both be accessible?)
2. Creating a MVC project and a submap with all the API's. (What about Separation of concerns?)
3. Creating a webapi project and make use of Area functionality where in MVC controllers are used to route.
4. Come to a conclusion that I better stick with MVC controllers to handel data communication for multipage applications.

Example solution structure:

```
Project.Core
Project.Services
Project.Data
Project...
```

Comment: You must look at that article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892301/Server-side-Data-Filtering-Sorting-and-Paging-with. Not related exactly what you need. But my think you can find everything in that article. Just download and investigate project.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it is a SPA where the routing is done with Angular, I'm trying to create a Multipage application where the routing functionality is handled by MVC controllers and only the data communication with Web Api.

Answer (score 2):

The WebAPI2 routing is separate from the MVC routing.  The beauty of the API 2 routing is that you can make it whatever you want, completely independent of the controller and action name.  Take the following example:

```
public class TriggerApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ITriggerApiService _triggerApiService;

    public TriggerApiController(ITriggerApiService triggerApiService)
    {
        _triggerApiService = triggerApiService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/trigger/{externalID}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTrigger(Guid externalID)
    {
        var triggerApiModel = await _triggerApiService.GetAsync(externalID);

        if (triggerApiModel != null)
        {
            return Ok(triggerApiModel);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

**Important things to notice:**

1. I'm extending ApiController and not just Controller
2. My method name GetTrigger is not the same as my route

So for your use case, I would use a single web project, but put all the APIs into their own controllers (that extend ApiController) and specify a route for each API.